# RSA encryption between PHP and Android/Java

Tags: java, php, openssl, rsa

I am wanting to encrypt data traffic between my Android application and the server running PHP.

With each new application startup connection, I am wanting to generate new public and private RSA keys in the app and on the server.

I have seen how to do this (relatively) simply within the Android app.

However, using OpenSSL on the PHP server, I am having a hard time understanding how to create the keys, extract the public key data in a form that I can send to and be used by the Android App and store the private key in the database to be re-used upon each request.

Note that I am not wanting to use phpseclib, if I can help it.

The other aspect I need to incorporate, is how to validate that the call arriving from the app is a legitimate call and not a hacker imitating.

Comment: It sounds like your trying to reimplement SSL/TLS in your first question. Is that really what you want?

Comment: In fact, I started simply wanting to encrypt conversations between the server and the application, using non-static keys.  I certainly don't want to get into creating certificates and certificate authorities - so, no, not full blown SSL/TLS